# pipenv not consistant from local to server

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

Im using pipenv to manage my dependencies, 
I have the following command working fine on my local machine:

`pipenv install --dev`

but when I run it on the server I get the following error:

```
n error occurred while installing pyparsing==2.4.1 --hash=sha256:530d8bf8cc93a34019d08142593cf4d78a05c890da8cf87ffa3120af53772238 --hash=sha256:f78e99616b6f1a4745c0580e170251ef1bbafc0d0513e270c4bd281bf29d2800 --hash=sha256:530d8bf8cc93a34019d08142593cf4d78a05c890da8cf87ffa3120af53772238 --hash=sha256:f78e99616b6f1a4745c0580e170251ef1bbafc0d0513e270c4bd281bf29d2800! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 237/237 — 00:00:30
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting pyparsing==2.4.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-nfz65sbh-requirements/pipenv-11553m_x-requirement.txt (line 1))']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyparsing==2.4.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-nfz65sbh-requirements/pipenv-11553m_x-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.11, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.10, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1.1, 2.4.2a1)', 'ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyparsing==2.4.1 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-nfz65sbh-requirements/pipenv-11553m_x-requirement.txt (line 1))']
```

I have handled pipenv errors before and most were pretty reasonable (clashes between dependency and sub-dependecies), but this one makes less sense to me as I did not specifically installed this package, but rather pipenv added it to the pipfile.lock and it doesnt find that version all together while locally that version is available for some reason.

I dont know which dependency is asking for that specific version either.

Pipfile.lock section:

```
"pyparsing": {
            "hashes": [
                "sha256:530d8bf8cc93a34019d08142593cf4d78a05c890da8cf87ffa3120af53772238",
                "sha256:f78e99616b6f1a4745c0580e170251ef1bbafc0d0513e270c4bd281bf29d2800"
            ],
            "version": "==2.4.1"
        },
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
you can see in the releases for pyparsing that this version does exist. See it [here](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/releases)

Comment: have you checked if pipenv itself has the same version on both your local machine and your server? I'm personally using just pip to install packages, and you sometimes get weird errors when pip itself is not up to date - which are completely gone after updating pip and trying to install the same package again.

Comment: they actually werent the same, so I updated pipenv and pip to the latest and so the all match. Still not working

Comment: There is also something going on with pyparsing releases itself. On the page you linked at the end, for 2.4.1.1, it states: "This is a re-release of version 2.4.1 to restore the release historyin PyPI, since the 2.4.1 release was deleted."

Comment: Possibly, you should be installing pyparsing==2.4.1.1, and your local dev machine is using a cached copy of 2.4.1 somewhere, hence it doesn't complain.

Comment: @00 I think you are right. That is really odd though, since when do you delete a version?? I dont have a way to change it manually as pipenv generates this automatically. I ended up updating a package (scipy) and it update pyparsing to 2.4.1.1, now works fine

Comment: The package may have been deleted accidentally. But, since that is easy to fix by re-uploading it again, it is more likely that there was a really bad bug (like a developer key/password, or using `eval` directly in the code, that should simply not be public.

Comment: All packages that depend on pyparsing (like scipy, in your case), will hopefully have updated their dependency on it (hopefully sooner than later), but it does mean there'll be versions of scipy and other packages that cause this error. Ideally (in my opinion), scipy should not have fixed the bug-fix version of pyparsing, to that it only required pyparsing==2.4.* and 2.4.1 would automatically have been replaced with 2.4.1.1, but apparently that was not so (and apparently, pip version resolution does not accept 2.4.1.1 when there's a restriction to '...==2.4.1'.

Comment: agreed. I think that `2.4.*` as a dependency for packages is the way to go here. I do think that pipenv should consider providing an automatic solution for this as people are always going to make mistakes like that.

Comment: if you want to publish a better written answer than I have, i will accept it so others can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that pyparsing have deleted a version, which is really weird.

I ended up updating a package (scipy) and it update pyparsing to 2.4.1.1, now works fine